# How do I install Ubuntu with LILO?

Tags: installation

Have previous version installed with LILO.  Current options are Win7, XP and UBUNTU.  previous upgrades have resulted in error messages. I wish to have a clean installation of UBUNTU 12.04 LTS. How do proceed without damaging Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Start With Normal Installation Procedure . as you done before 
On these steps

[image]

Just Select Something Else

Then

Select Previous Ubuntu Installed Drive

[image]

Format it into `ext4` and install in that ...

Hope this procedure will help you